# Promise value length returns 0

Tags: javascript, promise

When I `console.log` the value of a promise, I get the value but the length returns 0. And if I alert the value the promise returns, but its empty.

```
this.findClosestRiderToUser().then( data => {
    console.log( data );
    //alert ( data ) not working , returns empty 
    //console.log( data.length ) returns 0
})

//here is the promise code 
findClosestRiderToUser(){
    var promise = new Promise( (resolve, reject)=> {
        this.fetchAllRiders().subscribe( distance => {  
            this.distances.push( distance );
        });

        resolve(this.distances);
    })

    return promise;
}
```

Any thing I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You are resolving your `Promise` right away. I assume `fetchAllRiders()` is also async, since you are subscribing to it, which means that resolving right away won't leave you with anything.

You're going to need to `resolve()` inside of your subscribe:

```
this.findClosestRiderToUser().then( data => {
  console.log( data );
});    

findClosestRiderToUser() {
  return new Promise( (resolve, reject)=> {
    this.fetchAllRiders().subscribe(distance => {  
      this.distances.push(distance);
      resolve(this.distances);
    });
  });
}
```

However, if it returns only one distance, it will only give back on distance.

It looks like you're trying to wrap a subscribe pattern in a Promise pattern, which isn't going to really work since they're fundamentally different.

A subscribe pattern generally has a continuous feed of data. You *subscribe* so you can get told each time there is an update.

A Promise pattern resolves its value only once, when it is done.

If you need to collect all of the distances, you're going to have to either have some threshold to know when you're done, or if it has some kind of `onCompleted()` callback which will tell you that it's done.

If you want to get the closest rider updated each time an item comes through, you'll just have to calculate that inside the subscribe as well.